# Getting filtered list of another class within the DetailView which is looping through some other class

Tags: django, django-views

views.py

```
class UserPublicShell(DetailView):
        model = User
        template_name = 'users/public_shell.html'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/public_shell/', UserPublicShell.as_view(), name='public_shell'),
```

The view is showing the public page of a user.This user is not the logged in user in my app.
My problem is that I can't give my view only the posts which this user(the user whom the logged -in user is seeing) has written.

model of post:

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content= models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='post_pics')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()

        if self.image:
            img = Image.open(self.image.path)
            if img.height > 900 and img.width > 900:
                output_size = (900,900)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.image.path)
        
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: Can you share the model of your "posts"?

Comment: I have added the model of post but I don't think it matters at all!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `users/public_shell.html` template, you can access the `Post`s for which a user is the `author` with:

```
<!-- users/public_shell.html -->
{% for post in object.post_set.all %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

This uses the value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) as name for the relation in reverse, or if you did not provide one, it uses `modelname_set` with *`modelname`* the name of the model (here `Post`) in lowercase.

Comment: Could please explain it more? Do I have to change "object" with something else

Comment: @RZAMarefat: no, `object` is the `User` object. Django's `DetailView` passes the selected user as `object` to the template.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me.